# Standard K-mean algorithim

Tags: python, k-means

I am trying to implement the standard k-means algorithm in python but am encountering a type error(TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Point' and 'int'). Please help me understand what wrong am I doing. Below is my code:

```
from math import sqrt

class Point(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        
    def __add__(self,right):
        locx=self.x + right.x
        locy=self.y + right.y
        return Point(locx,locy)
    def __sub__(self,right):
        locx=self.x-right.x
        locy=self.y-right.y
        return Point(locx,locy)

    def __mul__(self,right):
        return self.x*right.x + self.y*right.y 

    def distance(self, other):
        return sqrt((self.x-other.x)**2+(self.y-other.y)**2)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Point(%d,%d)"%(self.x,self.y)



class Cluster(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.center = Point(x, y)
        self.points = []
    
    def update(self):
        temp=Point(0, 0)
        #print(len(self.points))
        count=0
        for point in self.points:
            count+=1
            temp += point
        print(len(self.points))
        self.center =  temp/count
        self.points = []
    
    def add_point(self, point):
        self.points.append(point)

def compute_result(points):
    points = [Point(*point) for point in points]
    a = Cluster(1,0)
    b = Cluster(-1,0)
    a_old = []
    for _ in range(10000): # max iterations
        for point in points:
            if point.distance(a.center) < point.distance(b.center):
                # add the right point
                a.add_point(point)
            else:
                # add the right point
                b.add_point(point)
        if a_old == a.points:
            break
        a_old = ...
        a.update()
        b.update()
    return [(x, y)] * 2
```

In' Class Cluster' I have defined a 'update' method where I am trying to do' self.center =  temp/count'. Thats where I am getting the error from.
the error is as folows:

```
<ipython-input-36-56b3a700600d> in update(self)
     42             temp += point
     43         print(len(self.points))
---> 44         self.center =  temp/count
     45         self.points = []
     46 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'Point' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the `Point` class doesn't have a '/' operator for dividing a point by an integer. is `Point` a class that you wrote? if so, you can just add the appropriate operator (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-overloading-in-python/ is a good starting place on how to do this). Otherwise, you will have to divide each part of the `Point` object by the integer and store it back to the appropriate member variable. Something like:

```py
        temp=Point(0, 0)
        count=0
        for point in self.points:
            count += 1
            temp += point
        print(len(self.points))
        self.center = Point(temp.x/count, temp.y/count)
        self.points = []
```